# MVC architecture for Tabpanel

Tags: extjs

After creating app in extjs by sencha cmd I have noticed that a tabpanel created as default. In fact I am going to work with this. In my tabpanel I want to use different forms for different tabs. I have also created views & controllers for different forms. My tabpanel contains fixed tabs, no need to create it dynamically. Now, how can I add those views to the corresponding tabs.

Also, I want a common file for all controllers and views and it should be loaded first. where to keep this file??

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is not to add your forms **into** tabs as items but to add forms and other components **as** tabs to the tab panel. The best is to assign aliases to components that will be tabs and then:

```
itmes:[{
    xtype:'your-form1'
},{
    xtype:'your-form2'
}]
```

where `items` is config option of the tab panel and form1 and form2 will be tabs.

For more info on aliases/xtypes see: http://extjs.eu/what-is-an-xtype/

It is not possible to combine more controllers/views/stores etc in one file. Ext strictly follows one-class-per-file concept.

Comment: Thanks saki to reply.In fact I have used alias to the tab items not as tabpanel items as you told.It's working fine now.

Comment: Glad you made it working. Accept the answer please if it helped.